# How to sort multiple NSArray ascending and decending order in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

I've got three arrays, priceArray, nameArray & discountArray. I display these array values in a tableView. Each Cell has Price,Name,Discount.

I want to sort the list by Price Low to High and vice versa, the items in the nameArray and discountArray need to be sorted corresponding to the price sort.

Likewise I want to sort by name from A-Z and vice versa and sort price and discount correspondingly.

```
1 cell -- 20,xxx,10%
2 cell -- 10,zzz,10%
3 cell -- 150,aaa,0%
4 cell -- 100,hhh,15%

By Price Low to High
   10,zzz,10%
   20,xxx,10%
   100,hhh,15%
   150,aaa,0%

By Name A-Z
   150,aaa,0%
   100,hhh,15%
   20,xxx,10%
   10,zzz,10%
```

Help me to sort like this.

Comment: There should be one array of a custom type that encapsulates the price, name and discount values.  Your life will become much simpler.

Comment: learn using sortDescriptor

Answer (score 8):

You cannot do what you are asking with 3 independent arrays. You need to gather all your information into a model object.

```
@interface Product:NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSNumber *price;
@property NSNumber *discount;

@end

@implementation Product  
//this is empty 
@end
```

You can then use `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the array of `Product`.

For example by price low to high.

```
NSSortDescriptor *priceSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"price" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [productArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[priceSortDescriptor]];
```

Change the `ascending:` argument to `NO` to sort high to low. Change the `key:` argument to `@"name"` to sort by name.

**EDIT**

To create your model object array , simply create the object and fill it with data.

```
Product *product = [Product alloc] init];
product.name = @"Widget";
product.price = @(3.65);
product.discount = @(.1);
```

So a Widget at $3.65 with 10% discount

Then add it to your mutable array.

```
NSMutableArray *productArray = [NSMutableArray array]; //create array only once 
for(thing in inboundInformation) {
    Product *product = //make and populate new product 
    [productArray addObject:product];
}
```

Typically you would loop round inbound information e.g JSON and create an object for each `Product` and add that object to your array for presentation.

Comment: Can you Help me how to Store these values in single Array in Model Object

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`NSSortDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html)

Some sample code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *ageDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"age" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *hireDateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"hireDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ageDescriptor, hireDateDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [employeesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: If you have simply array then in the place of key write nil, It will sort the array.

Comment: @ArpitParekh When entering nil, how is it sorting the array then? Alphabetically?

Comment: If you place nil in place of key, It will sort accruing to ascending or descending. Like this

Comment: When I would sort an NSArray alphabetically, I would use `[anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];`

Comment: Key is the property of your NSObject you want to sort on, it's all in the documentation

Comment: What if I have only Array of 10 elements with no key.

Comment: Then I would refer you to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and more specifically [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/OOP_ObjC.pdf)

Comment: This will give the OP what he wants, but does the OP actually know what he wants?  It looks like each value in the column is unrelated to the other columns, according the examples he gives.  That's strange and needs clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Price" key using to sorting the array. only we will change key. that key based sorting the array and return the values
for(int i=0;i<[price count];i++)
{
 NSMutableDictionary *cell=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [cell setObject:[name objectAtindex:i] forKey:@"Name"];
 [cell setObject:[percentage objectAtindex:i] forKey:@"Percentage"];
 [cell setObject:[price objectAtindex:i] forKey:@"Price"];
 [resultArray addObject:cell];
}
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Price" ascending:YES];
 NSArray *sortedArray=[resultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];

 for(int i=0;i<[sortedArray count];i++)
 {

 [price addObject:[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Price"]];
 [percentage  addObject:[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Percentage"]];
 [name addObject:[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"Name"]];

 }

 [tableview reload];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayName=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ravi",@"Arpit",@"Rikin",@"Prerit", nil];

 NSLog(@"%@",[arrayName sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:YES]]]);
```

OR

```
[anArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```